# Sort a list of tuples by first element and then the second element in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, how do we sort by first element and then the second element?

I know we can use something like `sortBy (compare on snd) lst` but that is only for second/first values. How do we compare by the first element and then compare by second element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the built-in Ord instance for tuples, so you can just use `sort`:

```
Data.List.sort :: (Ord a, Ord b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
```

Comment: Thanks! A follow-up: what if we want to sort by second element and then the first element?